# How can I hold Vcc logically for a while?

Tags: power-supply, power, capacitor, timer, low-power

I want to hold Vcc at 5 volts for approximately 35 seconds. I can set this with a capacitor and r-c circuit. Assume I'm not take too much current from the capacitor, about 5 uA.
But, during 35 seconds the voltage of the capacitor will gradually decrease. I don't want this. I want it to be 5 volts for 35 seconds. When the time is up, I want it to be 0 directly.

What is your suggestion?

Comment: we  don't know what circuitry you're considering. Please add a schematic!

Comment: Welcome to the SE site! You should clarify better constraints and purpose, but most of all show what you have worked out so far and why/where you are stuck. For example, I would say why 5 uA when you can limit drainage to nA (and less) with a MOS circuit ? What is the needed accuracy for that 5V? so, which reduction you can tolerate?

Comment: How much decrease in voltage can you tolerate?

Comment: You could combine a micropower boost converter (must have output disconnect function) with a capacitor/diode and a timing circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Easy with transistors:

R1,C1 sets the time constant -> make R1 pot to get exactly 35s, output voltage is at Q1 collector. After powering up when capacitor charges to 4.3v the Q2 closes and the Q1 also.

D1,R2 serves for quick discharge when power is unpluged.

It is possible to make it with one PNP transistor only but voltage on output will be cut more gradually.

[image]

[image]

Red is capactitor voltage, green is the output voltage

**Edit:**

More precise is to charge capacitor with constant current so you avoid a part of exponencial RC curve where cap voltage starts to change slow (>2/3 Vcc).

The charging current is set with R4 so change it to 10k potenciometer to controll timing.

The advantage off this version is a linear dependency between R4 and timing also.

The output voltage is at Q1 collector.

[image]

[image]

Green is capacitor voltage, blue is the output voltage.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider having an RC-timer attached to comparator. Yes, capacitor will slowly lose voltage, but you don't care anymore - your output is from the comparator, so it will output either 5V or 0V (given those are power rails and your comparator is rail-to-rail, which is normal these days).

---

The behavior will be the following:

0s: capacitor at 5V, comparator output 5V

10s: capacitor at 4V (or whatever), comparator output 5V

30s: capacitor at 1.2V, comparator output 5V

35s: capacitor at 1V->0.99V, comparator output 5V->0V

---

That is, if you set the threshold at 1V. You need some online calculators for timings, but it's not all that hard.

Bear in mind tho, that both R and C have tolerances, you can expect the thing to have +-10% or even 20% worst case (depends on specific parts of course). You can put a potentiometer in series with R to fine tune it.

If you really-really need precise 35s (not to millisecond, but, say, imperceptibly close, whatever that would mean), you may opt for a tiny microcontroller like attiny8. It can sleep all the time and only wake up to check time and change output; in best case scenario, it can consume microamps.

Comment: You don't *need* online calculators, it's pretty simple to compute yourself. This also requires that you have a stable 5 V power rail for the comparator, which it sounds like the asker might not have.